# Simple Spring constructor injection using autowiring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have a simple constructor injection example which I cannot get to work:

```
@Component
public class ScienceFilenameMetadataProcessor extends ScienceBasicFileProcessor implements Processor {


    private final FilenameParser parser;

    @Autowired
    public ScienceFilenameMetadataProcessor(FilenameParser parser) {
        this.parser = parser;
    }
}
```

The `FilenameParser` is an interface and contains several implementations. Identified using the @Qualifier.

I want to use this component from another class:

```
@Autowired
public SoarScienceCdfFileRouteBuilder(@Qualifier("cdfFileNameParser") FilenameParser filenameParser) {
    this.scienceFilenameMetadataProcessor = new ScienceFilenameMetadataProcessor(filenameParser);
}
```

I want to pass in the filenameParser to the constructor. But of course I want to avoid the new keyword otherwise spring is not going to initialize my class properly. However I want to avoid hardcoding the filenameParser implementation in the `ScienceFilenameMetadataProcessor` class.

How is this possible.

Thanks

Comment: Where and how do you use your ScienceFilenameMetadataProcessor?

Comment: It is there in the example. It is used from another class.

Comment: As `ScienceFilenameMetadataProcessor` is already a spring managed object, you don't have to use new in `SoarScienceCdfFileRouteBuilder`. But when creating `ScienceFilenameMetadataProcessor` as it needed `FilenameParser` type, you can create any of their implementation as bean, so that it will automatically inject and creates the object for `ScienceFilenameMetadataProcessor`

Comment: Thanks @kcsurapaneni - lets see an example please?

Comment: @user1472672 check the answer and let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided code defines a simple Spring application with a configuration class, interface, and several classes that implement the interface. The classes are then injected into Spring components using annotations.

#### 1. Interface `In`:

```java
public interface In {
    String getClassName();
}
```

This interface declares a method `getClassName()`.

#### 2. Implementing Classes:

##### a. ClassA:

```java
public class ClassA implements In {
    @Override
    public String getClassName() {
        return "Class A";
    }
}
```

##### b. ClassB:

```java
public class ClassB implements In {
    @Override
    public String getClassName() {
        return "Class B";
    }
}
```

Both `ClassA` and `ClassB` implement the `In` interface and provide their own implementation of the `getClassName()` method.

#### 3. Configuration Class `Config`:

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public In classA() {
        return new ClassA();
    }

    @Bean In classB() {
        return new ClassB();
    }
}
```

This configuration class defines beans named `classA` and `classB`. These beans will be injected into other components.

#### 4. Processor:

```java
public interface Processor {

    public In getIn();
}
```

##### a. ProcessorClassA:

```java
@Component
public class ProcessorClassA implements Processor {
    private final In in;

    public ProcessorClassA(@Qualifier("classA") In in) {
        this.in = in;
    }

    public In getIn() {
        return in;
    }
}
```

##### b. ProcessorClassB:

```java
@Component
public class ProcessorClassB implements Processor{
    private final In in;

    public ProcessorClassB(@Qualifier("classB") In in) {
        this.in = in;
    }

    public In getIn() {
        return in;
    }
}
```

#### 5. RouteBuilder Class:

```java
@Component
public class RouteBuilder {

    private final Processor processor;

    public RouteBuilder(@Qualifier("processorClassA") Processor processor) {
        this.processor = processor;
    }

    public Processor getProcessor() {
        return processor;
    }
}
```

#### 6. AnotherRouteBuilder Class:

```java
@Component
public class AnotherRouteBuilder {

    private final Processor processor;

    public AnotherRouteBuilder(@Qualifier("processorClassB") Processor processor) {
        this.processor = processor;
    }

    public Processor getProcessor() {
        return processor;
    }
}
```

#### 6. Accessing the result:

```java
String resultA = routeBuilder.getProcessor().getIn().getClassName();
// The value of result will be "Class A"
String resultB = anotherRouteBuilder.getProcessor().getIn().getClassName();
// The value of result will be "Class B"
```

---

Feel free to ask if you have any further questions!

Comment: Thanks for the great example @kcsurapaneni. Do imagine I have another RouteBuilder using the same processor, but want to inject a different implementation of In? I don't see a way to return ClassA? It should be possible to be able to provide the different implementations of In to the same processor somehow? Maybe I just need a factory for this?

Comment: @user1472672 Answer has been changed as per your comment in the answer. Have a look.

Comment: thanks. I guess that would work, but you end up duplicating the processor for every implementation of In which is not desirable

Comment: @user1472672 As you asked for different implementations for `Processor`, where one should return `ClassA` and the other `ClassB`, I think we can either have multiple implementations or one implementation with multiple attributes. If this helps, please accept the answer.